# Can't make or receive calls or texts, or connect to the Internet

Tags: connection-issues

My Samsung Galaxy S2 wont allow me to make or receive phone calls, messages, or texts. My provider is Vodafone; my Android version is 4.0.4.

I have tried my SIM in other phones and it works fine. It is just in this one that it doesn't work.

I have preformed a factory data reset and still have the same problem.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is the SIM detected correctly by the phone? Do you see a signal in the status bar? Any SIM errors displayed? Last question might sound stupid, but anyhow: If the answer to the first 3 questions is "no", are you sure you inserted the SIM card correctly (and not e.g. "upside-down" -- happened to me once ;)?

Comment: It was showing signal bars and sim detected for the vodafone networks and no sim errors displayed. unti i just tried the steps in the following link.. [link] http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Samsung-Galaxy-S2/Not-receiving-call-Can-t-make-calls/td-p/941679 [link].. now i have a no entry sign where my signal bars are supposed to be. @Izzy

Comment: As you already tried your SIM in other phones (so the SIM should be fine), have you tried it the other way round and put some other SIM into your phone? You could also go to a Vodafone shop for that. If other SIMs fail as well, and as you already did a factory-reset, all that's left is turn in the phone to service, unfortunately :(

Comment: yes other sims fail aswell, looks like i will have to send it off thanks for your help :) @Izzy

Comment: You are welcome! I then will write up a summary as answers, so possible future "searchers" have it easier to figure out. You're welcome to accept the answer then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to check out. Walk the list until your problem is resolved -- then skip all following:

1. make sure the SIM was inserted correctly (it easily happens to insert it the wrong way round)
2. does the same SIM work in other phones?

   - yes: SIM should be OK, phone probably "borked"
   - no: SIM "borked". Ask your provider for a replacement (Done.)
3. do other SIMs which work in other phones work in yours?

   - yes: very strange. Check with your provider to send you a replacement SIM: it's rare, but sometimes there can be incompatibilities (especially with older SIMs and newer phones).
   - no: pretty sure your phone is broken. Hand it in to service.

Some indicators to watch during the process, as they might prove helpful to service (and for combinations not covered above):

- Do you see a signal in the status bar?
- Are there any SIM errors displayed?

These two are pointing to an answer whether a SIM was detected at all. The phone should display a special symbol in the notification error if no SIM is found, and usually asks the user to insert one.

Comment: Tip: Add a bit of cardboard or something that will press down the sim card a bit more to make contact.... sim cards have various thicknesses... ;)